# Will a mulitouch touch screen equipped PC allow me to simulate real Android UI's without an Android device?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have recently purchased a Samsung Galaxy Tab as an Android 2.x testbed (I am aware that 2.3 might not run on it, but it appears to be a good 1.x - 2.x device with a large enough screen to approximate the variety of screens on different phones).

I would wait for Honeycomb equipped devices (such as the Motorola XOOM mentioned at CES 2011), but these are slated for some time in Q1 (likely end of Q1 for the Canadian market).

If I get a multitouch capable PC and install the Android SDK and simulator, will I be able to use the multitouch functionality of the PC with the simulator to approximate a real device?  Does anyone use a multitouch touch screen PC for Android development?  I assume that this would work as the PC would recognize my fingers like the mouse, but I'd like to find out before purchasing the PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will I be able to use the multitouch functionality of the PC with the simulator to approximate a real device ?

Probably not, simply because I doubt that the `qemu` emulation environment supports multitouch, or that the emulator image itself supports multitouch.

Comment: CommonsWare is right. The emulator does not support multitouch at this time. Why not use the Galaxy Tab for multi touch testing?

Comment: Hi guys!  Sorry for my slow response.  The problem with the Tab is that it's Android 2.2 and there doesn't seem to be much evidence for bumping to 2.3 or Honeycomb.  I took it back and pre-ordered a Motorola Xoom, which Google used this past week in their demo's...seems to be the closest thing to a reference implementation (like a Nexus), for Honeycomb.  Thanks again!